# Jquery / Script loading issue?

Tags: jquery, default, permalinks

Good morning guys,

I have some javascript-based 'gadgets' in my wordpress website (header, peeling-effect @ top-right corner, acordeon tabs in the content, etc... most of them loading from the [head] section) and they work like a charm all together when I choose to have my permalinks in default mode ({http://www.url.com/?p=123}). Site still works just fine when I change this structure to custom and open any post (let's say /%postname%.html) but not when I try to see my archives, or any of my categories, or some author's posts... it's like the 'deepness' of the URL breaks all this gadgets.

For example, in default mode, the URL for december 2010 archives page would be like:
{http://2.nadabueno.com/?m=201012}
and it all works fine.
However, in custom mode, this URL would be:
{http://2.nadabueno.com/2010/12}
and this j-query-based gadgets stop working (not to mention that the page-loading takes forever).

It's like having permalinks in custom mode does not allow this gadgets to work if you have a second -or more- trailing slash in the whole URL (considering as 'first slash' the one that comes immediately after the **.com**): {http://2.nadabueno.com/2010/12} (This is what I meant with 'deepness'... and of course if you go 'deeper', like in categories or sub-categories (which would add more slashes): {http://2.nadabueno.com/category/musica/}, it also won't work).

For you to have a better view :

http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/614/defaultpermalinks.jpg

{http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/889/custompermalinks.jpg}

In this last example, It's like the loading of the scripts get into an infinite loop trying to find the right path of the .js and .css files with no luck, which doesnt happen when you have set your permalinks to show the ID of the content (default mode).

I'm sorry if I explained this wrong (if I did just let me know). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the PHP code in your wordpress templates that includes the jQuery & plugins? Probably in header.php.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a lot of the effects plugins are coded into the site with relative URLs starting with "js/".  That means that there's a "js" directory on the server at the top level of the deployment, and you're exactly right: pages served with URL strings that put them at lower directory levels won't work.

Here's an example from the source of a page:

```
<link href="curt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/curt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The only thing I can suggest is to fix the templates (or whatever) so that all those scripts are imported from absolute URLs. It looks like paths of the form "http://2.nadabueno.com/js/whatever.js" will work. Note that the relevant CSS files are also being pulled in from relative URLs, and will need the same treatment.

You may want to consider combining those too — there are *way* too many separate imports on that site.

Comment: It had to be that! I'll try what you suggest and will get back to you to comment how it went, in case anyone else ever need a solution for this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_enqueue_script` in your theme's functions.php with the absolute (local) path to the scripts and it should be fine.